# Como permitir caracteres especiales en RDLC report

Tags: c#, mvc, report, rdlc

Buen dia, estoy utilizando rdlc report, pero al generar mi reporte lo descargo y distintos dispositivos en algunos se muestra bien y en otros no... ya que ciertos text incluyen ' ó í con tildes y me muestra el texto en esta manera...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo en C# es el siguiente:

```
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension;
        string[] streams;
        Warning[] warnings;
        var deviceInfo = @"<DeviceInfo>
        <EmbedFonts>None</EmbedFonts>
        </DeviceInfo>";
        //byte[] bytes = localReport.Render("PDF", deviceInfo);
        byte[] bytes = localReport.Render("PDF", deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf;charset=utf-8";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + "Report"+".pdf");
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

Y en mi reporte .rdlc estoy utilizando la fuente normal "Arial" no se a que se deba y maximo en unos dispositivos si y en otros no.

Comment: Yo tuve un error parecido que me volvió loco, y llegue a la conclusión de que el problema eran las fuentes que al no estar embebidas dependiendo del dispositivo fallaban. Prueba a quitar el `<EmbedFonts>None</EmbedFonts>` y debería funcionarte. Eso si, el tamaño de los pdf aumentará bastante.